# display order of the string to the data stored in the database

Tags: database, oracle, pdo

for example I have data as found in the table below

tabel order

```
-----------------------------------------
   id_order    no_order       order_date
-----------------------------------------
     1         0000001       12-01-2013
     2         0000002       15-01-2013
-----------------------------------------
```

tabel item_order

```
--------------------------------------------------
   id_item_order       id_order      order_name
--------------------------------------------------
       1                 2           Product 1
       2                 2           Product 2
       3                 2           Product 3
       4                 2           Product 4
--------------------------------------------------
```

then I want to display the data from database with join as below

```
--------------------------------------------------
  id_item_order     order_name       no_order
--------------------------------------------------
      1             Product 1        0000002 A
      2             Product 2        0000002 B
      3             Product 3        0000002 C
      4             Product 4        0000002 D
--------------------------------------------------
```

how to display the character "A - n" located behind no_order according to the amount of data that relate item_order with id_order in table order?

please help me. thank you

Comment: @valex: Oracle, can you help me

Comment: What does `A`..`D` stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c766f/21/0) for testing

```
select i.id_item_order, i.id_order,
        o.no_order || chr(rownum + 64) as no_order
from item_order i
inner join "order" o on o.id_order = i.id_order;
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about oracle But i tries this using SQL and it works well

```
select TIO.id_item_order,TIO.order_name,[TO].no_order + char(ROW_NUMBER() 
 OVER (order by id_item_order )+64) as no_order 
 from  
 TableItemOrder TIO inner join TableOrder [TO] on [TO].id_order=TIO.id_order
```

It worked for me